# Фрагмент, заменяющий активность

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

хочу написать приложение, состоящее из фрагментов, но почитав в интернете кучу статей о работе с фрагментами, так и не понял, как  реализовать такое ТЗ: Есть два фрагмента, `MainFrag`  имеет кнопку, `SeconFrag` - ничего, как сделать так, чтобы при запуске приложения вместо `MainActivity` отображался `MainFrag`, и при нажатии на кнопку на этом фрагменте осуществлялся переход на `SeconFrag`?

Comment: Просто в onCreate активити отобразите 1 фрагмент. Так он запустится при старте активити

Comment: фрагменты не могут существовать сами по себе, без хост-активити. то есть вам нужно запустить активити, а в ней открыть фрагмент в контейнере на разметке активити, потом по нажатии кнопки заменить один фрагмент другим в этом контейнере на разметке

Comment: [Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

Activity это родитель фрагментов. Он в обязательном случаем должен быть. Либо же придумать динамический хост.
В Activity мы подгружаем уже Fragment. В этот Fragment, можем закинуть еще один фрагмент и тд.
Вы можете сделать так, чтобы загрузилась MainActivity и в нее закинуть по дефолту загрузку фрагмента. По сути у вас в Oncreate создаться при запуске фрагмент, который вы уже замените(на свое усмотрение) другим.